# How to paste below, not to the right nor to the left

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, visual-block, paste

## Question

I think you see the problem... How can I paste directly below? Is there a way?

## Setup

I have this table and I want to copy/yank the 3 × `|` in **visual block mode** and then paste it:

```
| sign    | example           |
| ---     | ---               |
| %       | dir/test.txt      |
| %:t     | test.txt
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt
| %:e     | .txt
```

`p` (lowercase):

```
| sign    | example           |
| ---     | ---               |
| %       | dir/test.txt      ||
| %:t     | test.txt           |
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt  |
| %:e     | .txt
```

With `P` (uppercase):

```
| sign    | example           |
| ---     | ---               |
| %       | dir/test.txt      ||
| %:t     | test.txt          |
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt |
| %:e     | .txt
```

---

Stuff like `:+1put` does **not** work...

---

---

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you do not have spaces after the text at the last three lines? E.g. if `$` denotes the line end, it looks like this?

```
| %:t     | test.txt$
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt$
| %:e     | .txt$
```

In that case, I would copy/yank the 3 `|` from the first 3 lines using *visual-block-mode* when the cursor is on the last `|` of the first line using: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Then, you need to enable [virtualedit mode](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27), which basically allows the cursor to move beyond the actual text, so you can position the cursor right before the position of where the `|` should be placed:

```
:set ve=all
```

So in the following picture, the ¶ denotes the cursor:

```
| sign    | example           |
| ---     | ---               |
| %       | dir/test.txt      |
| %:t     | test.txt         ¶
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt
| %:e     | .txt
```

And now you can paste using <kbd>p</kbd> which should result in:

```
| sign    | example           |
| ---     | ---               |
| %       | dir/test.txt      |
| %:t     | test.txt          |
| %:p     | /tmp/dir/test.txt |
| %:e     | .txt              |
```

And optionally disable **virtualedit** mode using `:set ve=`